# Двоеточие или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

**Демократия принесла в политическую жизнь множество преимуществ - учет мнения большинства и политическую конкуренцию, представительство интересов и возможность выбора.**

Как вы считаете, целесообразна ли замена тире на двоеточие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь одна часть явно раскрывает смысл другой. Возникает вопрос: а именно? какие же преимущества? Может быть, кто-нибудь решит, что здесь использован авторский знак. Но мне кажется, что замена тире на двоеточие целесообразна.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие, конечно, напрашивается.

Answer (score 0):

Тире достаточно часто, вопреки правилам ,заменяет двоеточие. Но в данном случае - после обобщающего слова (множество преимуществ) перед однородными членами - все-таки нужно двоеточие.